# Joi Array validation , force at least one item based on another field value

Tags: joi

I have the following validation block

```
  // POST /api/resources
  createResource: {
    body: {
      .... require at least 1 item 
      permissions: Joi.array().items(Joi.object().keys({
        level: Joi.string(),
        level_id: Joi.string().hex(),
        canWrite: Joi.boolean()
      })),
      private: Joi.boolean().required()
    }
  },
```

I would like to require at least 1 item in permissions when the private flag is false
Based on an previous question ( using includes() and not items() ) , I should use something like :

```
 permissions: Joi.array().items(Joi.object().keys({
        level: Joi.string(),
        level_id: Joi.string().hex(),
        canWrite: Joi.boolean()
      })).when('private'{is:false,then:Joi.required()})
```

but this doesn't work
Anyway to validate it ?
thanks for feedback

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your validation formatting is a little odd so I'm going to assume you want to validate the entire request object. e.g.

```
{
    createResource: {
        body: {
            permissions: [{...}, {...}],
            private: false
        }
    }
}
```

But if I've assumed wrong you can still pick the working bit out..

I don't recommend mixing POJOs with `Joi` objects. The issue with your example is that `Joi` isn't aware that the `permissions` and `private` keys are related to the same object. To fix this you want to write a schema for the *entire* request object like this.

```
Joi.object().keys({
    createResource: Joi.object().keys({
        body: Joi.object().keys({
            permissions: Joi.array().items(
                Joi.object().keys({
                    level: Joi.string(),
                    level_id: Joi.string().hex(),
                    canWrite: Joi.boolean()
                })).when('private', {is: false, then: Joi.required()}),
            private: Joi.boolean().required()
        })
    })
});
```

---

So this will validate `true` when `private` is `true` (no permissions required)

[image: Validation]

...`false` when `private` is `false` and there are no permissions

[image: Validation]

..and `true` when `private` is `false` and `permissions` is populated correctly.

[image: Validation]

[Joi Tester](http://framp.me/joi-tester/)

Comment: Thanks a lot ... !  have to get more in depth with Toi ... seems to ba a powerful tool

Comment: The tool I used in the pictures is linked at the bottom of my answer. The source code can be found [here](https://github.com/framp/joi-tester).